# PM2 Error: Cannot find module when using ecosystem file

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm having an issue with pm2.

If I start my app with

```
cd /my/path
pm2 start server.js
```

everything works correctly, but if I use an `ecosystem.config.js` file, then it gives the following error

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
Error: Cannot find module '/my/path/server.js'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
```

my ecosystem file is configured as follows

```
module.exports = {
    "apps": [{
        "name": "MyApp",
        "script": "server.js",
        "cwd": "/my/path" 
    }]
}
```

I tried uninstalling pm2, updating npm and reinstalling node_modules, but still I can't understand why it says a module is missing in my file (expecially because it works when not using the ecosystem file)

Comment: Is pm2 installed globally? If so, then it sounds weird... Maybe show us how you run the command that uses the ecosystem file (probably through script), and where is the `ecosystem.config.js` located? Also what's your OS?

Comment: @AndreyPopov pm2 is installed globally, yes, and is located on a different folder (e.g. ```/other/path/```). I'm running pm2 on a Synology NAS, and I tried running the ecosystem file with the command above (so ```pm2 start /other/path/ecosystem.config.js```)

Comment: Ah, maybe it's the Synology that's causing issues - it's not exactly working as a common storage. Surely your setup is looking okay for a standard usage, and you shouldn't be forced to touch it in any specific way. Unfortunately I'm not competent in Synology, but you could check some identical issues [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/installing-node-red-on-synology-nas/14329/11) and [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4272). Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this command: `pm2 start src/server.js`

or other folder name before server file name

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the ecosystem.config.js is in the root of your project as well as your server entry file (server.js) and specify your script as below:

```
module.exports = {
    "apps": [{
        "name": "MyApp",
        "script": "./server.js"
    }]
}
```

Comment: If you have questions - use the comments section above. Answers should really contain answers.

Comment: Do I have to keep the ecosystem file in the same folder of my project? Is it a requirement? Because if I need to run 2 apps from the same ecosystem file, then it MUST be located outside the projects folders...

Comment: The reason for having such a file is to be able to put it wherever you like and run multiple instances :) So no, it's not a requirement for sure!

Comment: @Andrey thank you, guess this is why they said its great for microservices. Luca just what Andrey said, it's not a must, i suggested that incase you were only running one application

Answer (score 0):

Reading from https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

```
Field   Type        Example         Description
name    (string)    “my-api”        application name (default to script filename without extension)
script  (string)    ”./api/app.js”  script path relative to pm2 start
cwd     (string)    “/var/www/”     the directory from which your app will be launched
```

I would try:

- with `"script": "./server.js"` (kind of strange, I know)
- remove the `cwd` parameter and setting `./my/path/server.js`

Comment: I wouldn't go this way. First suggestion is optional and shouldn't make any difference. Second one would change cwd from what he has.

Comment: I also tried to type the full path in the script property but it gives the same error